# Remove a selection listener on a table item

Tags: java, swt, tableviewer

I have a table where multiple table items are available.
Out of them, for some table items background and foreground color is set.

On selection of a colored item,since the text color was white, the text is difficult to read
So, I need to change the forground color to default ie. black.
I had done it using the selection listener

```
private SelectionListener selectionListener;

    private void mouseTrackListener() {
        selectionListener = new SelectionListener() {

            @Override
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                        ((TableItem) e.item).setForeground(null);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            }
        };

        this.table.addSelectionListener(selectionListener);

        this.table.removeSelectionListener(selectionListener);
    }
```

And the color got changed successfully.

But now I am selecting any other item which is not colored, so I want to remove the above selection listener and set the text color to colored ie. white.
I am not getting how to use  `this.table.removeSelectionListener`.

Can some one please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remember the selection listener somewhere, probably a field in the class managing the table.

```java
private SelectionListener listener;

...

listener = new SelectionListener() ....


...

table.addSelectionListener(listener);

...

table.removeSelectionListener(listener);
```

Be sure to only create the listener once (possibly in the class constructor).

An alternative is to just add the listener (once) and then test a flag in the listener to decide if you setForeground.

Comment: I tried it, but it seems it is not working. I wrote the below method  

      `private void mouseTrackListener() {
             selectionListener = new SelectionListener() {
             @Override
              public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                ((TableItem) e.item).setForeground(null);

            }

            @Override
            public void widgetDefaultSelected(SelectionEvent e) {

            }
        };

        this.table.addSelectionListener(selectionListener);

        this.table.removeSelectionListener(selectionListener);
    }
`

Comment: I can't read that. [edit] your question and add the details there.

Comment: Added this code in question

Comment: You don't just call addSelectionListener followed immediately by removeSelectionListener. You call the add when you decide you need to add the listener, and call remove when you decide you don't need it.